# How to set keyboard key using registry

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, keyboard, registry, co

Im looking for a way to write a script (hopefully in python) that remmap specific keyboard keys using the registry. 
For example: switching only between the enter and the space bar.

In addition I would like to know if there is away to set the value of the spacebar key.

for example:  making the spacebar write the word "space".

Thanks (:

Comment: For the record c# good too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open source project called *Sharp keys* to change keys in your registry. Its written in C#, but you may give it a try.

Link: http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

While the question is old, the problem is still relevant. I'd suggest using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Following would trigger Space key when Enter is pressed and would print "space" when space key is pressed:

```
Enter::
Send, {Space}
return

Space::
Send, space
return
```